# Showing an element based on a select choice - jQuery, HTML

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show a second select element only if a certain option of a first one is selected.

Should be straight forward but it doesn't work.

So I have a few of select elements of class "one" each followed by a select o class "two".
Within document ready function I first hide all of the selects of class "two": `$('.two').hide();` works fine.
Then I have a function (also within document ready function) to show a next select of class "two" if a certain value is picked from the select of class "one".

```
$('.one').change(function() {  
    var two= $(this).next('.two');  
    if ($(this).val()==3){  
        if(two.is(':hidden')) {  
            two.fadeIn(50);  
        }else{  
            two.fadeOut(50);  
        }  
    }  
});
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide your html snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have other elements between the two selects, so you need to use the [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) method like this

```
var two= $(this).nextAll('.two:first');
```

The `next(selector)` method will return the **exactly next** sibling **if** it matches the selector..

Additionally i believe that you have a wrong nesting of IFs.. Now you show/hide only if the value is 3 (both the hiding and showing happens if the value of the `.one` is 3)

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/UXS2X/

change

```
if ($(this).val()==3){  
        if(two.is(':hidden')) {  
            two.fadeIn(50);  
        }else{  
            two.fadeOut(50);  
        }  
    }
```

to

```
if ($(this).val()==3){  
        if(two.is(':hidden')) {  
            two.fadeIn(50);  
        }  
    } 
 else{  
        two.fadeOut(50);  
     }
```

Comment: "Most likely you have other elements between the two selects" - yes, that was the problem, there was a line break.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
if ($('select.two option:selected').val()==3){
...
}
```